# How to iterate a list from a to z - to scrape data and transform it into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Currently working on a scraper that collects the data of german insurances - here we have a comprehensive list of data insurances-companies from **a to z**

our **menbers:**

https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder the overview on 478 results:

for the **letter a**:
https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter=A
for the **letter b**:
https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter=B

and so forth: btw: see for example one page  - of a company:
https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder/ba-die-bayerische-allgemeine-versicherung-ag-47236

With the data, we need to have the contact-data and the adress

Well I think that this task could be done best with a tiny bs4 scraper with request and putting all the data to a dataframe:
I use `BeautifulSoup` for parsing the HTML and `Requests` for making HTTP requests. Best method - yes I guess is `BeautifulSoup` and `Requests` to extract the contact data and address from the given URL (see below and also above).
First of all we need to defines a function `scrape_insurance_company` that takes a URL as input, and then send an HTTP GET request to it, and extract the contact data and address using `BeautifulSoup`.

Finally, we need to return a dictionary containing the extracted data. well since we need to cover the characters from a to z we have to iterate here: we iterate through a list of URLs containing the insurance companies and call this function for each URL to collect the data. Subsequently  we use Pandas to organize the data into a DataFrame.

**note:** i run this  on google-colab:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def scrape_insurance_company(url):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the HTML content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # Find all the links to insurance companies
        company_links = soup.find_all('a', class_='entry-title')
        
        # List to store the data for all insurance companies
        all_data = []
        
        # Iterate through each company link
        for link in company_links:
            company_url = link['href']
            company_data = scrape_company_data(company_url)
            if company_data:
                all_data.append(company_data)
        
        return all_data
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch the page:", response.status_code)
        return None

def scrape_company_data(url):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the HTML content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # DEBUG: Print HTML content of the page
        print(soup.prettify())
        
        # Find the relevant elements containing contact data and address
        contact_info = soup.find('div', class_='contact')
        address_info = soup.find('div', class_='address')
        
        # Extract contact data and address if found
        contact_data = contact_info.text.strip() if contact_info else None
        address = address_info.text.strip() if address_info else None
        
        return {'Contact Data': contact_data, 'Address': address}
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch the page:", response.status_code)
        return None

# now we list to store data for all insurance companies
all_insurance_data = []

# and now we iterate through the alphabet
for letter in range(ord('A'), ord('Z') + 1):
    letter_url = f"https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter={chr(letter)}"
    print("Scraping page:", letter_url)
    data = scrape_insurance_company(letter_url)
    if data:
        all_insurance_data.extend(data)

# subsequently we convert the data to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(all_insurance_data)

# and finally - we save the data to a CSV file
df.to_csv('insurance_data.csv', index=False)

print("Scraping completed and data saved to 'insurance_data.csv'.")
```

well at the moment all looks like so - i get in google-colab-terminal:

the insurance:

```
Scraping page: https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter=A
Scraping page: https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter=B
Scraping page: https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter=C
Scraping page: https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter=D

Scraping page: https://www.gdv.de/gdv/der-gdv/unsere-mitglieder?letter=Z

Scraping completed and data saved to 'insurance_data.csv'.
```

bit the list is still empty... i still struggle here a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check whether the elements you want to select are contained in `response` / `soup`; the ones you are addressing do not appear to be present. So your ResultSet `soup.find_all('a', class_='entry-title')` is empty and the `for loop` do not start to fill `all_data`

Scraping the links of the companies per letter page and fill your `all_data` list:

```
# Find all the links to insurance companies
company_links = soup.select('ul.ibmix-download-teaser__list li a')
```

Find address and contact info on each company site:

```
# Find the relevant elements containing contact data and address
contact_info = soup.select_one('[href^="mailto"]')
address_info = soup.select_one('.ibmix-article__rte p')
```

Comment: Hi there dear HedgeHog - many thanks for your fast reply. Awesome:  right - i need 
 to  using the suggested selectors  in order to to find the contact data and address information on each company's page.  Thank you alot.  Now it works very very fine! You made my day.